# How to show current date time in Textblock in TopAppBar-WinRT

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

i am trying to show the current sysdatetime in Top App bar and i was wondering anyway i can do that in XAML for win store apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your page you can set Page.TopAppBar, and Page.BottomAppBar like this:

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <TextBlock Text="Your text" />
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

From there, you can whether bind the Text property, if you're using the MVVM pattern, or simply assign a value in the code behind of the page, by giving a name to the TextBlock element.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    private string _resDateTime;
    public string ResDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _resDateTime;
        }
        set
        {
            _resDateTime = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ResDateTime");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _timer.Tick += TimerOnTick;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerOnTick(object sender, object o)
    {
        ResDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

add to the code behind

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
```

and put on xaml

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ResDateTime}"></TextBlock>
    </AppBar>
  </Page.TopAppBar>
```

hope it will help